# SQLite username check with EditText value

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hi i have bit problem in login actually i"m trying to tesing login by checking username from     databse and edit text value but its not working . the following is my codes .
i'm bit confussed about to get the EditTextvalue

```
package com.example.employeemanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    EditText unameedt;
    String unam;
    String pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        Button logbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
        Button signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
        EditText unameedt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText passedt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("Employeemanager", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        unam = unameedt.getText().toString();
        pass = passedt.getText().toString();
        logbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

        {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
                        "SELECT  username, password from Employee", null);

                if (c != null) {

                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            String uname = c.getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndex("username"));
                            String upass = c.getString(c
                                    .getColumnIndex("password"));

                            if (uname.equals(unam)) {
                                StartActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Home.class));

                            }

                        } while (c.moveToNext());

                    }

                }

            }
        });

        signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Emp_signup.class));
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your

```
unam = unameedt.getText().toString();
pass=passedt.getText().toString();
```

into butonClick event

```
logbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

{
unam = unameedt.getText().toString();
pass=passedt.getText().toString();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple but looks like a big thing while start learning Android. What you doing now is you got the value in onCreate

```
    unam = unameedt.getText().toString();
    pass = passedt.getText().toString();
```

So, now the `uname`and `pass` is `empty` because while onCreate there is no values set to the corresponding `EditText`.

In `OnClick` Method you comparing the Value from Edittext and from database

```
    if (uname.equals(unam)) {//if(usernamefromDatabase.equals(emptyValue))
         StartActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Home.class)); 
      }
```

Thats where the problem is.

What you want to do now is get the `unam` and `pass` values in onClick

```
    unam = unameedt.getText().toString();
    pass = passedt.getText().toString();

   if (uname.equals(unam)) {//if(usernamefromDatabase.equals(valueyouentered))
         StartActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Home.class)); 
      }
```

It should work now.